# QtCore.QTimer.singleShot lags when calling a function iteratively

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qtimer

I have pyqt gui with some text display that is updated periodically via function
updateTelemetry()

Here is how my code works. When the user clicks the button, the buttonHandler is called. And updateTelemetry is called iteratively every 10s.:

```
def buttonHandler(self):
    self.monitor=true
    self.updateTelemetry()

def updateTelemetry(self):
   try:
        #update values on gui
   finally:
       if self.monitor:
          QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self.updateTelemetry)
```

This approach works, and lets me get an update around every 10s. However, every 10s, the entire gui freezes for a few seconds and then updates. Something that I'm doing seems to be blocking. I'm not sure how that is happening. I thought that qtimer.singleshot would create a separate thread?

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Is it the update to the GUI that is taking a long time, or something else in your code (eg reading from a database or web page or something)?

Comment: Also, timers are not threads. But threads may not help depending on your answer to me above question.

Comment: @three_pineapples the update process queries a device for some values. And this inherently takes a few seconds. How come threads won't help for that?

Comment: Your OP was not clear as to the cause of the delay, so I sought clarification. Threads **will** help keep the GUI responsive when reading data from the device. What I meant was if you were then writing a lot of information to the GUI, and it was the GUI calls that were slow (not the device interaction), then threading cannot speed that up (because GUI operations must always occur in the main thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `QTimer` does not create a separate thread. `QTimer` simply emits a signal in the main thread after a given timeout. As such, everything (including your device reading code) is still running in the main thread.

You should move the code that reads from your device to a `QThread` and emit a signal from the `QThread` to the main thread where you can update your GUI. **GUI updates must only be done from the main thread**. Only signal emission is thread safe!

The following is a rough implementation of a `QThread`.

```
class MyThread(QObject):
    send_data_to_gui = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True: 
            # get data from device
            self.send_data_to_gui.emit(data_from_device)
            time.sleep(10) 

...

thread = QThread()
my_thread = MyThread()
my_thread.send_data_to_gui.connect(my_slot)
my_thread.moveToThread(thread)
thread.started.connect(my_thread.run)
thread.start()
```

Note that in it's current form, the `QThread` actually has it's own event loop, so you can do all sorts of complicated things (however the `while True` is blocking the event loop at the moment). As the thread has an independent event loop, you could replace the `while True` with a `QTimer`, configured to fire every 10 seconds (make sure the `QTimer` is actually created in the thread though. `MyThread.__init__` still runs in the main thread but the contents of `MyThread.run` will be executed in the new thread). You also might want to add the ability to shutdown the thread, or add other functionality I don't know about!

If you have trouble with your implementation, feel free to post a follow-up question on stack overflow!